# linux find exec positional parameter

Tags: linux, find, exec, csh

I'm currently using the following line to find a number of scripts and execute them.  The scripts are named as : my_script_0.sh, my_script_1.sh, etc.

```
find $MY_HOME/SHELL/my_script_[0-9].sh -type f -exec csh -c '"$1" >& "$logfile" &' {} \;
```

This works fine except that now I would like to create a unique `$logfile` for each of the executed scripts.
I realize that using awk I could do something like this to grab the number of the file and then potentially use that in the logfile name.

```
find $MY_HOME/SHELL/my_script_[0-9].sh -type f | awk -F"\\.|_" '{print $4}'
```

The issue is that I don't believe I can use awk with the original statement since I need the positional parameter to be the full path/filename.

Ideally I would like to simply use another positional parameter with the find -exec command.  Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-exec` option to `find` simply excutes the given arguments. Since you pass it `csh -c ...` it will start a new shell to which you can optionally pass some arguments (one being `{}`). These arguments are then set as positional arguments `$1, $2, $3, ... ,$n` in the new shell. In this case the `find` results are passed one by one and used as `$1` in the shell.

I'll suggest an alternative to your `find` command which uses a loop instead:

```
foreach script ( $MY_HOME/SHELL/my_script_[0-9].sh )
    csh -c "$script >& $script:r.log"
end
```

The `:r` strips the extension of the variable it's attached to so we get the logfile: `my_script_n.log` for the script `my_script_n.sh`.

I checked out these references on C-shell syntax:

- [CSH Scripting Basics](http://tomecat.com/jeffy/tttt/cshvars.html)
- [IBM](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.baseadmn/doc/baseadmndita/c_var_file_sub.htm)

Comment: It appears that csh doesn't have the for loop?

Comment: @McArthey Ok, this answer works in (ba)sh, running csh in a subshell. Sorry.

Comment: Great, thanks!  It appears that simply using `foreach script ( $MY_HOME/SHELL/my_script_[0-9].sh )` takes care of it.

Comment: Something still isn't exactly correct since an error results: `Missing }.`

Comment: @McArthey Yes, as I said it will only work in (ba)sh, not csh.

Comment: @McArthey I just updated the for-loop to work in `csh`. Let me know how it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42900/discussion-between-herman-torjussen-and-mcarthey)